# Hide missing reference errors in error window

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-errors, msbuild, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on some code in a remote location using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013. Due to restrictions, I don't have available a couple of .DLL files required to successfully build my project, however periodically I'd like to run a build to check for errors not related to the missing references (e.g. I have a strong tendency to define methods in interfaces as public).

Unfortunately the missing references are numerous (~2000) and finding other errors is a needle-in-haystack scenario. Is there a way to turn off the missing references check in Visual Studio? Or perhaps to hide Missing Reference errors in the error window?

One option I've found reasonably successful is to sort by error description and to simply navigate to the beginning and ends of the error lists, and fix all that aren't Missing Reference Exceptions, but this is still a clunky and slow workaround, that does not actually solve the issue at hand.

Comment: Can you upload detailed build log somewhere and specify which exact warnings you want to hide. Technically- there is a $(NoWarn) property which allows you to pass list of warningIds to disable during compilation. Have you tried it ?

Comment: $(NoWarn) seems to be for compiler warnings only. This is for compiler errors.

Comment: Can't you create library shim using Microsoft Fakes to make your project build-able ?

Comment: For some reason my puny brain hadn't thought of that. Write that up as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a shim library using Microsoft Fakes to make your project build-able.